# Basic disk encryption in Ubuntu

Tags: encryption, privacy

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so feel free to explain like I'm five (I wont be offended)

I'm starting work as a private therapist and have brought a T450 Thinkpad with the express intent of installing Ubuntu as I consider it to be generally more secure and virus proof than windows. As I'll be storing a lot of sensitive client info (voice recordings, session notes etc.) I want to be able to encrypt my external hard drive (A 1TB WD My Passport) to add some security.

The laptop itself I'm not planning on encrypting, as anything sensitive will be saved directly to the external drive, but if anyone answering feels there is a reason that I should also encrypt the Laptop I'm happy to do so.

As this is my first experience with an OS that isn't windows, anything that has a GUI would be best, or something that is very easy to follow if it does not have a GUI. I'm intending to learn how to use Linux better over time, but need the simple stuff so I can be safe from the start.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a good reason to keep a drive encrypted.

- Use a high quality password/passphrase, that you can remember.
- Please set up a routine with **frequent backups** (and test that it works to recover the system). The backup can be both encrypted and unencrypted. If you keep the drive for backup in a safe place, it could be OK with unencrypted backup, which makes it easier to recover.

There is no back door, if something goes wrong with the encrypted drive. Then you must rely on the backup.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you whether to encrypt your laptop, but personally I would recommend it especially on newer devices that can efficiently handle the encryption/decryption with very little overhead.

The external drive can easily be encrypted separately though, and definitely should be if it is holding personal info. Ubuntu provides a guide here and it can almost all be done with a GUI I think: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage